# Older Nvidia cards no longer get along with 14.04.02

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I volunteer to administer a half dozen Ubuntu PCs for a small non-profit.  They are all similar - older PCs with 1.5gb memory outfitted with 32-bit Ubuntu with Nvidia GeForce 6200 cards to help with performance (basic browsing) and have been working fine until the roll-out of 14.04.02.  When upgraded to .02, all of the PCs work OK with the nouveau drivers but are too slow. Noting that Nvidia stopped supporting the 6200 in the 346.35 driver package, I apply the last-supported 304.125 drivers (which are suggested by .02) - after which the PCs boot to the graphical login screen OK - but after login, the desktop / icon colors are wrong (desktop appears black, icons are just black squares with white/blue outlines), and the mouse / keyboard are unresponsive. Tried Ubuntu 15.04 / Nvidia 304.125 to see if anything cleared up - but same issues.  SO I have reverted back to 14.04.01, which works fine with the Nvidia 304.125 drivers, and have turned off software updates, which I hate to do.  Some searching on these forums show I am not alone when it comes to using "older" Nvidia cards with 14.04.02 (so much for LTS).  What broke? Thoughts welcome - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After updating to 14.04.2 you should probably take advantage of the hardware enablement stack (I've had pretty good results using nvidia-304 so far):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

To install the kernel 3.16* version (utopic), do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-304/trusty linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-utopic
```

To install the kernel 3.19* version (vivid), do this instead:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-304/trust linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid
```

or you could install both to find out which gets the best results for you.

Reboot and choose "advanced options for ubuntu" when you get to the grub menu. Then, select which kernel to use and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Additionally, you can use

```
sudo apt-mark hold <packagename>
```

to prevent upgrades of any specific package so you can keep application version and still allow other system updates.

To change things back to default, run:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <packagename>
```

to unhold the application.